# Javascript: how to remove second level array by top level index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, splice

I have a nested array in javascript. The top level has a numerical index, the second level arrays contains various data. I want to be able to remove an element from the array using the top level index.

```
    var my_array = [];

    my_array[12] = ['cheese', 'egg', 'ham'];
    my_array[24] = ['balloon', 'frog'];
    my_array[33] = ['chicken', 'goose'];
```

How do I delete my_array[24]? I have tried using splice with $.inArray but inArray returned the index as -1. I don't want to use indexOf because of it's browser limitations - also I think it will give me the same problem as inArray.

Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation is awkward to me...could you just show exactly the array you have and the array you need?

Comment: If I understand correctly: [`delete my_array[24];`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: @adeneo `delete` won't affect the `length`. But, the property/index will be removed/`undefined`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - in this particular case the length will be 34, as that's how many indices there really are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_array.splice(24, 1);` will remove the item at index = 24.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

If want to remove `frog` from main array index 24 by it's known index of 1

`myArray[24].splice(1,1);`

If want to search for `frog` anywhere and remove parent.

```
var term='frog';
my_array=$.grep(my_array,function(element,i){
     return $.inArray( term, element) !=-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function:

```
function deleteByIndex(arr, index) {
    var new_arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] && i!=index) {
            new_arr[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return new_arr;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/59Pj4/)

call it like `var new_array = deleteByIndex(my_array, 24);`

Comment: Your method works, but is more complicated than the one I have marked as the correct answer.